# Taxonomies are not showing in the category dropdown

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I am working on clients website and I have added the Custom post type plugin for creating the new section and I have also added the taxonomies for that.

In my page, I have added the default categories drop-down select box but the problem is that, it is not showing the taxonomies added for the Custom post type.

So, I went to the `wp-includes/category-template.php` and edited the file.

```
 function wp_dropdown_categories( $args = '' ) {
    $defaults = array(
        'show_option_all'   => '',
        'show_option_none'  => '',
        'orderby'           => 'id',
        'order'             => 'ASC',
        'show_count'        => 0,
        'hide_empty'        => 1,
        'child_of'          => 0,
        'exclude'           => '',
        'echo'              => 1,
        'selected'          => 0,
        'hierarchical'      => 0,
        'name'              => 'cat',
        'id'                => '',
        'class'             => 'postform',
        'depth'             => 0,
        'tab_index'         => 0,
        'taxonomy'          => 'project_type',
        'hide_if_empty'     => false,
        'option_none_value' => -1,
        'value_field'       => 'term_id',
        'required'          => false,
    );

    $defaults['selected'] = ( is_category() ) ? get_query_var( 'cat' ) : 0;

    function wp_list_categories( $args = '' ) {
    $defaults = array(
    'child_of'            => 0,
    'current_category'    => 0,
    'depth'               => 0,
    'echo'                => 1,
    'exclude'             => '',
    'exclude_tree'        => '',
    'feed'                => '',
    'feed_image'          => '',
    'feed_type'           => '',
    'hide_empty'          => 1,
    'hide_title_if_empty' => false,
    'hierarchical'        => true,
    'order'               => 'ASC',
    'orderby'             => 'name',
    'separator'           => '<br />',
    'show_count'          => 0,
    'show_option_all'     => '',
    'show_option_none'    => __( 'No categories' ),
    'style'               => 'list',
    'taxonomy'            => 'project_type',
    'title_li'            => __( 'Categories' ),
    'use_desc_for_title'  => 1,
   );

   $r = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
```

In place of `'taxonomy' => 'category'`, I added this `'taxonomy'=> 'project_type'`, Now the taxonomies are showing but the search according to the drop-down select box is not working. It is showing page not found.

Do I have to go the Setting > Permalinks and click save button?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you flush your rewrite rules after activating your CPT under settings > permalinks? (visiting that page is enough) That is necessary when working with own CPTs.

Comment: muah. never ever a good idea to hack core wp files.. i'd rather see your code, that you use to pull the terms, since this usually works out of the box. so i hence you used a wrong function or something..

Comment: plus another one. as stated before, you don't need to hack wp core files. if you update wp, you'll overwrite your changes. to get, what you have right there, you can pass arguments to the function to overwrite the default values: `wp_dropdown_categories(['taxonomy' => 'project_type'])`

Comment: @honk31. Yes you are right but I have to show the taxonomies in the select box so can you please tell the solution for that.

Comment: @honk31. Can you please tell the solution?

Comment: @RahulKumar permalinks: generally speaking, when you create a new cpt or ct you need to reset your permalink structure, yes. the best way to do so is head over to settings permalinks and simply save the page once more, so wp remembers your new entry types. have you done that?